# Haskell State monad: get updated state after sequence

Tags: haskell, state, monads

I'm building a C# compiler in haskell as part of a compilers course.
I am using the state monad, and the problem lies in the code for the block. I'm using the state to wrap the env of declared vars. When parsing a block, I want to extend this state (because of declarations inside the block), but afterwards return to the original block (since declerations don't go outside the block). However, I want to know the size of the new updated state first. So I have the code below:

```
type EnvState = State Env (Int, Code)
type Env = M.Map String Int

fStatBlock :: [EnvState] -> EnvState
fStatBlock block = do origEnv <- get
                      xs      <- sequence block -- prelude sequence
                      newEnv  <- get
                      put origEnv
                      return (M.size newEnv, concatMap snd xs)
```

The env is of type Data.Map.

My problem is that the newEnv isn't the updated env after sequence, but equal to the origEnv. Therefore, the size returned is 100% dependent on the size of the original env, and does not change no matter what is inserted in the sequence. (I have tested the insert method and it works).

Is this somehow due to lazy evaluation? Weird execution order? Or should this give the new, updated env and am I doing something wrong somewhere else? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you please insert definition of `sequence` function? If this is is a standard function from `base` package, then what's the type of `block`? It's always useful to add complete type signatures to functions you need help with (if this is not obviosly clear from the context).

Comment: I have updated the code fragment, you are right I removed a bit too much info

Comment: Maybe `block` doesn't actually change the `Env` at all?  try `runState (sequence block)` with some initial map with a `block` you expect to change things, and making sure that it does return a changed map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Justin L. suggests, the problem probably is that `block` is not changing the `Env`.  Here's your example code, unchanged, with some test code added to make a complete program.  Function `setValue` produces an `EnvState` that changes the `Env`.  Using `setValue` in the call to `fStatBlock` **does** result in a size that is one greater than it would be if based on the original `env`.

**complete program**

```
import Control.Monad.State 
import Data.Map as M

type Code = [Int]


-- begin original code ------

type EnvState = State Env (Int, Code)
type Env = M.Map String Int

fStatBlock :: [EnvState] -> EnvState
fStatBlock block = do origEnv <- get
                      xs      <- sequence block -- prelude sequence
                      newEnv  <- get
                      put origEnv
                      return (M.size newEnv, concatMap snd xs)

-- end original code -------


setValue :: String -> Int -> EnvState
setValue name value = state (\env -> ((0,[]), insert name value env))

main = do
    let env = fromList [("x", 5), ("y", 10)]
        fsb = fStatBlock [setValue "a" 15] 
    print $ fst $ fst $ runState fsb env
```

**results**

```
$ ./main 
3
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort in your answer! I have looked at the code again and found my issue. The problem was when I had nested blocks. If I had multiple levels the top one would always return the size of the 1st enclosed block, no matter what happens at a deeper level. Solved it by having all args to fStatBlock return the correct envSize, and then returning `return (maximum $ map fst xs, concatMap snd xs)`